# Action array not executing in Parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I can't seem to get my Actions to execute in parallel. They are executing in sequence.. Could somebody help me?

```
Action<Type_arg1,Type_arg2>[] actions = new Action<Type_arg1,Type_arg2>[count];

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    actions[i] = new Action<Type_arg1,Type_arg2>(carryOutAction);
int iter = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(actions, (thisaction) =>
{
    thisaction(arg1,arg2,iter);
    iter++;
});
```

Comment: a) Please provide a [mcve] b) What makes you think they are in sequence? c) `iter++` is not thread-safe and can't be used reliably in `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: To be clear - the code is **not** a [mcve] until we can copy and paste it into a console app and run it without compile errors (e.g. complaining that `carryOutAction` is not defined).

Comment: This will execute the same action with the same parameters multiple times. Is this the requested behavior? If so, the whole block can be rewritten `Parallel.For(0, count, i => carryOutAction(arg1, arg2, i));`

Comment: @vc74 thanks very much, you helped me fix my issue. If you turn your solution into an answer i will accept it as the best - thanks :).

Comment: @Neeta too late ;)

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted is actually running in parallel (or at least unordered, which is a good hint, that it is in parallel.)

```
PS> scriptcs
scriptcs (ctrl-c to exit or :help for help)

> var count = 20;
>
> Action[] actions = new Action[count];
>
> for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
* {
*     var contextValue = i;
*     actions[i] = new Action(()=>Console.WriteLine(contextValue));
* }
>
> Parallel.ForEach(actions, (thisaction) =>
* {
*     thisaction();
* });
0
6
7
8
9
11
12
14
16
17
18
19
10
13
3
1
4
2
5
15
{
  "IsCompleted": true,
  "LowestBreakIteration": null
}
```